# Room Database Does Not Show Under Device File Explorer

Tags: android, android-room

Summary: I have checked the instance of database which was not null.  However, the database has not been created by looking at Device File Explorer. My goal is to produce a database including tables that I would like to look at to make sure it looks correct before I go further working on the code.

Detail: The following code is to create instance of Room.databaseBuilder based on 'parks_database'.

```
private lateinit var INSTANCE: ParksDatabase

fun getDatabase(context: Context): ParksDatabase {
    synchronized(ParksDatabase::class.java) {
        if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                ParksDatabase::class.java,
                "parks_database"
            ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
            if(INSTANCE == null)
                Timber.d("INSTANCE is NULL")
            else
                Timber.d("INSTANCE is NOT NULL")
        }
    }

    return INSTANCE
}
```

In my Logcat screen, it shows 'INSTANCE is NOT NULL'.

Here is the code that I wrote to create database in ViewModel:

```
private val parksRepository = ParksRepository(getDatabase(application))
```

Here is the ParksRepository code:

```
class ParksRepository(private val database: ParksDatabase) {
    val parks: LiveData<List<DomainPark>> = Transformations.map(database.parksDao.getParksWithAddresses()) 
    {
        it.asDomainModel()
    }

    init {
        Timber.d("Injection ParksRepository")
    }

    suspend fun refreshParks() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Timber.d("refreshParks() is called")
            val parkList = ParksApi.retrofitService.getParks(ParksApiService.API_KEY)
            database.parksDao.insertAll(parkList.asDatabaseModel())
        }
    }
}
```

I have researched tutorials or websites.  I am not sure what I am missing here to create database.  Does the INSTANCE value of NOT null means it should have created database even I do not find it on Device File Explorer (Yes, I did refresh the explorer).

Thank you for your time!

Comment: are you using the canary version of android studio to look at the databases?

Comment: Where are you looking in the File Explorer?

Comment: @karandhillon I dont think I use canary version. I am using 3.6 version.

Comment: @Bink I look at Device File Explorer on Android Studio.